# Docker and MongoDB: Start Mongo and Import Data via Dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mongoimport

I need to use MongoDB with Docker. Up until now i am able to create a container, start the Mongo server and access it from the host machine (via Compass).
What i want to do next is import data from a script into the Mongo database that is running in the container. 
I'm getting the following error when trying to import the data:

> Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Where's what i'm doing...

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb_db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/db/Dockerfile
      args:
        DB_IMAGE: mongo:4.0.9
    ports:
      - 30001:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_DATA_DIR: /data/db
      MONGO_LOG_DIR: /dev/null

  db_seed:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/db/seed/Dockerfile
      args:
        DB_IMAGE: mongo:4.0.9
    links:
      - mongodb
```

**mongodb Dockerfile:**

```
ARG DB_IMAGE

FROM ${DB_IMAGE}

CMD ["mongod", "--smallfiles"]
```

**db_seedDockerfile:**

```
ARG DB_IMAGE

FROM ${DB_IMAGE}

RUN mkdir -p /srv/tmp/import
COPY ./app/import /srv/tmp/import

# set working directory
WORKDIR /srv/tmp/import
RUN mongoimport -h mongodb -d dbName--type csv --headerline -c categories --file=categories.csv #Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
RUN mongo mongodb/dbName script.js
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can i solve this issue? 
I would like to keep the current file organisation (docker-compose, mongodb Dockerfile and db_seed Dockerfile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason for the issue. The import command is being executed prior to the mongo service being started.
To solve this issue i created a .sh script with the import commands and execute it using ENTRYPOINT. This way the script is only executed after the **db_seed** container is created. Since the the **db_seed** container depends on the **mongobd** container, it will only execute the script after the mongo service is started.

**db_seedDockerfile**

```
ARG DB_IMAGE

FROM ${DB_IMAGE}


RUN mkdir -p /srv/tmp/import
COPY ./app/import /srv/tmp/import

ENTRYPOINT ["./srv/tmp/import/import.sh"]
```